# How to cast context into listener in BroadcastReceiver's onReceive which is registering from Fragment?

Tags: java, android, interface, broadcastreceiver, fragment

This is the BroadcastReceiver in which context is cast into listener interface:

```
public class StatusChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private IStatusChangeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        listener = (IStatusChangeListener) context; // getting error in this line when using LocalBroadcastManager

        if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkConnected()) {
            listener.onConnected();
        } else {
            listener.onDisconnected();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the interface:

```
public interface IStatusChangeListener {
    void onConnected(String status);
    void onDisonnected(String status);
}
```

Now I'm implementing the `IStatusChangeListener` interface in a Fragment like below:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements IStatusChangeListener {
    //some codes

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        StatusChangeReceiver r = new StatusChangeReceiver();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter("connectionStatus"));
        //getContext().registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter("connectionStatus"));
    }

    @Override
    void onConnected(String status) {
        //some log here
    }

    @Override
    void onDisonnected(String status) {
        //some log here
    }
}
```

When I use `getContext().registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter("connectionStatus"));` then I get no error but I get no call in the implemented listener's methods in the Fragment.

When I use `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter("connectionStatus"));` then I get java.lang.ClassCastException error:

```
<ContextName> cannot be cast to IStatusChangeListener
```

So what is the solution to overcome this problem?
Is there any standard way to implement BroadcastReceiver which casts context into listener?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the context is instance of `IStatusChangeListener` or not.

```
public class StatusChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private IStatusChangeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(context instanceof IStatusChangeListener){
           
        listener = (IStatusChangeListener) context; // getting error in this line //when using LocalBroadcastManager

        if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkConnected()) {
            listener.onConnected();
        } else {
            listener.onDisconnected();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IStatusChangeListener {

    MainFragment mainFragment;
    
    @Override
    public void onConnected(String status) {
        if (mainFragment!=null){
            mainFragment.onConnected();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisonnected(String status) {
        if (mainFragment!=null) {
            mainFragment.onDisonnected();
        }
    }

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mainFragment = MainFragment();
        //do fragment trasaction
        //get transaction
       transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment ); transaction.commit();

}
}
```

Comment: So, If the context isn't an instance of IStatusChangeListener then the whole code won't execute, right?

But I need to execute the whole code.

Comment: but how?, If your `context` is not an instance of the `IStatusChangeListener`, what will you do, class cast will be thrown.

Comment: I asked the question for the answer. You're asking the same question to me.
There may be a different way to implement such thing.

Comment: Sorry, but I hope you understand the issue, what you want is is not possible, unless the context is not implementing `IStatusChangeListener`

Comment: Yes, got your point. 
My fragment is implementing IStatusChangeListener which is not enough.

So if I pass a listener while instantiating StatusChangeReceiver and then I assign the listener in onReceive rather than casting the context, can I get the behaviour I expect?

Comment: Point to mark that, the fragment is not a child of `context`, activity is.

Comment: if the host activity implements `IStatusChangeListener` then you can get it in the activity, from there you can call upon the fragment.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate the way if I implement IStatusChangeListener in activity then how to call upon the fragment?

Comment: I need to have a snippet of your code, where you inflate the fragment, then i can update my answer

Comment: onCreate() of main activity

Comment: need code of at least how you create an instance of the fragment.

Comment: transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainFragment());
transaction.commit();

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

```
public class SomeClass implements IStatusChangeListener,Parcelable {
  // implement the required methods
}
```

**Activity class**

```
SomeClass someclass = new SomeClass();

intent.putExtra("someclass",someclass)
```

**Reciever Class**

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundel b = intent..getExtras()

        if(b != null){
         SomeClass someclass = b.getParcelable("someclass");

        //rest of your logic
       }
    }
```

Edit:

just put the instance of the `SomeClass` in the intent which you will be wrapping with a `PendingIntent` and you can use the `intent` and the rest of the logic remains same and by this way your `MainActivity` need not to implement `IStatusChangeListener`

Comment: @Md. Ikramul Murad check this and let me know if you face any issues

Comment: Due to some issue, I can't check it at this moment. I'll check and let you know soon. Anyway, if some other fragments implement the IStatusChangeListener then we need to add more code in onReceive() method. Which isn't a good approach.

Comment: I dont think you need to add more checks in onrecieve, you just check if the received `intent` has any bundle and if so that means it has the object implementation you need, you don't need to know which fragment sent the object, all you care for is you have the `object` to work on

Comment: and if your Fragment say `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` has different logic to execute in `onConnected`  and `onDisconnected`, just create different objects in those Fragments  with the necessary logic and let the `onRecieve` handle the executions

Comment: So for every different fragment I need to add more logic to handle.

Comment: You dont have to add "more" logic. matter of fact, it's the same except in my approach you would just move the implemented methods to a different class

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours for the appropriate way to implement such a solution to this problem, I've found a way finally.

In this way, a `setListener()` method is exposed so that `Fragment` or `Activity` can set the listener by sending an instance of `IStatusChangeListener`.

```
public class StatusChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private IStatusChangeListener listener;

    public void setListener(IStatusChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkConnected()) {
            listener.onConnected();
        } else {
            listener.onDisconnected();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the interface:

```
public interface IStatusChangeListener {
    void onConnected(String status);
    void onDisonnected(String status);
}
```

Now, it is required to have an instance of `IStatusChangeListener` interface instead of implementing the `IStatusChangeListener` interface. And then, pass this instance of `IStatusChangeListener` to `setListener()` method.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment { //Not implementing the interface

    private IStatusChangeListener listener = new IStatusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        void onConnected(String status) {
            //some log here
        }

        @Override
        void onDisonnected(String status) {
            //some log here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        StatusChangeReceiver r = new StatusChangeReceiver();
        r.setListener(listener); // pass the IStatusChangeListener instance
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter("connectionStatus"));
    }
}
```

Note: Always use `LocalBroadcastManager` if you register `BroadcastReceiver` from `Fragment`.